# Function with return values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have written a function which takes the Name as input and returns Suffix.
I want to return the position of suffix in a name with a function.
How can i do that.
Could any one please help me doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no need to create special function fot this. it already exists in t-sql.
its name is [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms188395.aspx)
Example:

```
declare @pat varchar(128)
set @pat = '_suf'
select login, Patindex('%'+@pat, login) as suffix_index from clients
```

Comment: The problem with using Patindex is that, if the name has sililar pattren twice then it will find the position of first occered position in word.
Example: Advin Dovin DO . patindex returns 6 not 13.

Comment: you may compose your pattern as '%'+Name - this matches your purpose

Comment: Could u please help me out doing this.

Comment: look at the example i've added to my answer.

Comment: I think i need to write patindex('%'+@pat+'%',Login) is it.?

Comment: % - is the search pattern which matches to the sequence of any symbols. if you want to find suffix, you should not include % after pattern like you offer. eg. you have two rows with field values pref_value_suff and pref_suff_value. the pattern %suff will return only one row with pref_value_suff value (because it ends with suff), but the pattern %suff% will return both rows. see the difference?